# how do I get 2 different foreign key from 1 primary key relation?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, database-connection

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MNee.png)

how to retrieve data id = 6 in tbl_direksi_perusahaan?

what about writing it on the laravel controller?

I have tbl_paket_pl and have a relation id_profil_penyedia = 6,id_profil_pedia as the primary key associated with tbl_direksi_perusahaan, how do I retrieve tbl_direksi_company data

```
public function lays_suratpesanan($id)
{
    if(!Session::get('login')){
        return redirect('/login')->with('alert','Kamu harus login dulu');
    }
    else{
    $sesi = Session::get('id'); 
    $paket = DB::table('tbl_paket_pl as a')
        ->select('*')
        ->join('tbl_profile_penyedia as b', 'a.id_profil_penyedia', '=', 'b.id_profil_penyedia')
        ->join('tbl_kriteria as d', 'a.id_kriteria', '=', 'd.id_kriteria')
        ->join('tbl_pagu as e', 'a.id_pagu', '=', 'e.id_pagu')
        ->join('tbl_pembayaran as f', 'a.id_pembayaran', '=', 'f.id_pembayaran')
        ->join('users as g', 'a.id_userpp', '=', 'g.id')
        ->join('tbl_jenis_penyedia as h', 'b.id_jenis_penyedia', '=', 'h.id_jenis_penyedia')
        ->join('tbl_cabang_ut as i', 'b.id_cabang_ut', '=', 'i.id_cabang')
        ->where('id_paket_pl',$id)
        ->get();
    $profilp = DB::table('tbl_profile_penyedia as a')
        ->select('*')
        ->where('a.id_profil_penyedia',$id)
        ->get();
    $direksi = DB::table('tbl_direksi_perusahaan as a')
        ->select('*')
        ->join('tbl_profile_penyedia as b', 'a.id_profil_penyedia', '=', 'b.id_profil_penyedia')
        ->where('a.id_profil_penyedia', $id)
        ->get();
    $pesanan = DB::table('tbl_pesanan_pl as a')
        ->select('*')
        ->join('tbl_bmn2 as b', 'a.kode_bmn', '=', 'b.kode_bmn')
        ->join('tbl_paket_pl as c', 'a.id_paket_pl', '=', 'c.id_paket_pl')
        ->join('tbl_profile_penyedia as d', 'c.id_profil_penyedia', '=', 'd.id_profil_penyedia')
        ->join('users as e', 'd.id_user', '=', 'e.id')
        ->join('tbl_kriteria as f', 'c.id_kriteria', '=', 'f.id_kriteria')
        ->join('tbl_paket as g', 'd.id_paket', '=', 'g.id_paket')
        ->join('tbl_pagu as h', 'c.id_pagu', '=', 'h.id_pagu')
        ->join('tbl_pembayaran as i', 'c.id_pembayaran', '=', 'i.id_pembayaran')
        ->join('tbl_ruang2 as j', 'a.kode_unit', '=', 'j.kode_ruang')
        ->join('tbl_jenis_penyedia as k', 'd.id_jenis_penyedia', '=', 'k.id_jenis_penyedia')
        ->join('tbl_kategori_belanja as m', 'g.id_kategori_belanja', '=', 'm.id_kategori_belanja')
        ->join('tbl_cabang_ut as l', 'd.id_cabang_ut', '=', 'l.id_cabang')
        ->where('a.id_paket_pl',$id)
        ->get();
    $undanganpl = DB::table('tbl_undangan_pl as a')
        ->select('*')
        ->join('tbl_paket_pl as b', 'a.id_paket_pl', '=', 'b.id_paket_pl')
        ->where('a.id_paket_pl', $id)
        ->get();
    $suratpesanan = DB::table('tbl_suratpesanan_pl as a')
        ->select('*')
        ->join('tbl_paket_pl as b', 'a.id_paket_pl', '=', 'b.id_paket_pl')
        ->where('a.id_paket_pl', $id)
        ->get();

    return view('pembelian_langsung/undangan/lays_suratpesanan', compact('sesi','paket','profilp','pesanan','undanganpl','suratpesanan','direksi'));
    // $pdf = PDF::loadView('pembelian_langsung/undangan/lays_suratpesanan', compact('sesi','paket','profilp','pesanan','undanganpl','bmn2','kategorib','pagu','pembayaran','kriteria','kodeu'));
    // return $pdf->download('Berita Acara Negosiasi.pdf');
        }
    }
```

can you help me solve it

Comment: `how to get data from tbl_direksi_perusahaan take to tbl_paket_pl?` Sorry I don't understand what do you mean here ? could you explain more please

Comment: can check again, maybe now understand @CodeScale